# How to serialize apache spark's MatrixFactorizationModel in Java

Tags: java, serialization, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib, collaborative-filtering

I am building a recommendation system using Apache Spark `MLlib` and Java. Once the `MatrixFactorizationModel` is built, I have serialized it as a java object and when retrieving the model, I am getting the following exception.

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.apache.spark.OneToOneDependency cannot be found by
>   org.scala-lang.scala-library_2.10.4.v20140209-180020-VFINAL-b66a39653b

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: which version of spark are you using?

Comment: I am using spark 1.4.0

Comment: what version of scala is in your dependency?

Comment: scala 2.10.4 is used in the dependency

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are usiong incompatible versions of scala and spark.
`Spark 1.4.0` need `scala version 2.11.6` but are using scala version 2.10.4(from your error stack).

PS:You could find out compatible versions from [here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-core_2.10/1.4.1)